# How to resolve the import error for numpy in python3.8 on linux?

Tags: python, numpy

I've installed python3.8 and the up-to-date version of numpy.

```
# pip list
Package          Version
---------------- ---------
appdirs          1.4.4
certifi          2020.6.20
distlib          0.3.0
filelock         3.0.12
numpy            1.19.0
opencv-python    4.2.0.34
pandas           1.0.5
pip              20.1.1
pipenv           2020.6.2
PyMySQL          0.9.3
python-dateutil  2.8.1
pytz             2020.1
scipy            1.5.0
setuptools       41.2.0
six              1.15.0
virtualenv       20.0.25
virtualenv-clone 0.5.4
```

Here's c simple code:

```
import numpy
```

but python can't import numpy.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr  9 2019, 14:30:50)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 188
    exec(source_object, scope)
SyntaxError: unqualified exec is not allowed in function 'decorator' it is a nested function
>>>
```

how can I resolve this trouble?
help me. plz..

Comment: NumPy no longer supports Python 2.

Comment: You say "in python3.8", but the interactive header says "Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr  9 2019, 14:30:50)". Your Python is screwed up.

Comment: Linux runs Python2.7 by default, if you installed Python3 you need to execute your scripts with `Python3 script.py` or create a symlink for the regular Python command.

Comment: thank all of you. I haven't caught up with there're both python 2.7 and 3.8 on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the script by using the command `python3 script_name.py`. The reason for the error could be because script is using python 2.7.5 version.

Answer (score -1):

You may have to check your `PYTHONPATH`

To print the python search path type this in python shell

```
import sys  
print sys.path
```

Here you should find the directory containing your numpy library. But if it is missing then manually locate the directory containing numpy library and add it to your python path using this code

```
sys.path.append('your directory path here')
```

then try importing again